# How to create a rest coldfusion component to open a pdf and html files

Tags: rest, pdf, coldfusion

Basically, we`ve got a front end of application in html5 with a link to call a rest cfc (Coldfusion10) component that would open a pdf or html file.

I am new to resful api and need help with rest call from a client to the rest component. I have this file that I need to open written in traditional cfml.

Thank you

Here is the cfc

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="summary">   
  <cffunction name="getempconfstatement" access="remote" returnType="binary" produces="application/xml"  httpmethod="get">  
    <cfargument name="empplan_id" type="numeric" restargsource="path" />
    <cfargument name="effective_date" type="string" restargsource="path" />

    <cfset var pdfout = "">

    <cfdocument format="PDF" srcfile="http://10.200.5.2/v3/myinfo/confstatement.cfm?empplanID=21546&sum=0&bydate=03/18/2014" filename="pdfout" overwrite="yes" name="pdfout" >
    </cfdocument>

    <cfreturn pdfout>
</cffunction>
```

Here is the test rest call updated:

```
 <cfhttp url="http://10.200.5.2/rest/v2_selections/empconfstatement" method="get" result="res">
   <cfhttpparam type="url" name="empplan_id" value="21546">
   <cfhttpparam type="url" name="effective_date" value="2014-03-18">
 </cfhttp>
 <cfset pdfdata = res.filecontent>
 <cfset binary = toBinary(pdfdata)>
 <cfset tmpFile = getTempFile(getTempDirectory(),"pdf")>
 <cfset fileWrite(tmpFile, binary)>
 <cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="inline;filename=new.pdf" />
 <cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tmpFile#" deletefile="no">
```

I am getting this string:

> ogPJHB6WAPZh8Iqh0BmpH9xeWvn4v3fXaF4rDUD/QphtgIHlBNdIaW4mJOCeU+NrYHF8/sxHp1WNbWuYkv8R6zseHvvUr/Pv4gP5i0/m6NdWTvh1pM5lmTTx8qGzHyzytEnm6TRqw

Edited cfc component:

```
 <cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="empconfstatement">    
<cffunction name="getempconfstatement" access="remote" produces="plain"  httpmethod="get">  
    <cfargument name="empplan_id" type="numeric" restargsource="path" />
    <cfargument name="effective_date" type="string" restargsource="path" />

    <cfset var pdfout = "">

    <cfhttp url="http://10.200.5.2/v3/myinfo/confstatement.cfm" method="get" result="pdfout">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="empplanID" value="21546">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="bydate" value="03/18/2014">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="sum" value="0">
    </cfhttp>

    <cfset temp =  fileReadBinary(pdfout)>

    <cfreturn toBase64(temp)>
</cffunction>
```

Now, I am getting Failed to load PDF document. It seems the file is not read in cfc. Is there way to read a file as a html page beside cfhttp?

Comment: As the error says, you aren't returning a binary object.  I've managed to get a similar type of function working, using http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/12/10/Proof-of-Concept--Working-with-Remote-PDF-Data as a guide.  Basically, you take the PDF, convert it into "one large string" and recompile it back up on the other end.

Comment: I'm not sure if you read the link, but you'll want to return a string representation of the PDF in base64.  Then, `cfhttp.filecontent` convert that string back to binary. Then convert that binary back to a PDF.

Comment: Thanks Chester, I followed your example raymondcamden link and at least got the browser to try to open a file in pdf format. Now, I am getting error failed to load document. I think the file is not read. I posted edits.

Comment: So to be sure, you're using a CFM page, which calls out to a CFC using CFHTTP, where, inside that CFC, you're using CFHTTP to again call out to a CFM page?

Comment: My process for debugging this was to ensure that each of the PDFs generated on the server were correct.  I had an issue where a PDF was generated, but, due to rights issues or whatever, I / CF couldn't open the file, so it would generate an error.  An overview of the process might help, also.

Comment: I have html5 page with that calls a rest service to display a summary to a user. I do not know if it is possible but, I want to use the same summary.cfm page that I had before. It is either in html or pdf format depending on a parameter. This page works fine by itself. 
In my question I am using cfhttp cfm page to call rest component for testing purposes. In the rest components I was trying to use cfttp to access that summary.cfm page.

Comment: Would using cfhttp to access summary.cfm and serve it as a string work or, I need different way to access summary.cfm? Or, perhaps easier to access summary.cfm with pdf parameter and return it from rest component as pdf?